# JS-GRID: How to set default value

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I'm using [JS-GRID](http://js-grid.com/demos/). How can i set default value to input?

I tried following code. But not successful

[Demo Link Here](http://js-grid.com/docs/#localization)

```
fields: [
{ name: "addresse", type: "text", width: 500, validate: "required",
            insertValue: function(){
                return "My Default value";
            }
        },
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works, but probably even better would be to override `insertTemplate` instead custom implementation (in this case you don't need to take care of `insertValue`).

```
insertTemplate: function() {
    var $result = jsGrid.fields.text.prototype.insertTemplate.call(this); // original input

    $result.val('My Default Value');

    return $result;
}
```

As described in this issue on GitHub https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/471

Answer (score 1):

Okay. My problem has solved.

```
insertTemplate: function() { 
      return $("<input>").attr("type", "text").attr("value", "My Default value");
}
```